# Merging union Observables

Tags: c#, extension-methods, observer-pattern, system.reactive

I am having a scenario where I need to execute observables that depends on the result of the first one. However I need to keep the result of the first observable. I couldn't find any extension that would help me do this. For instance `SelectMany` does a projection of the first observable discarding the source results. Therefore I made my own extension:

```
public static IObservable<T> MergeWithResultPropagation<T>(this IObservable<T> src, Func<T, IEnumerable<IObservable<T>>> elems)
{
    return src.SelectMany(result => elems(result).Union(new[] { Observable.Return(result) }))
        .SelectMany(r => r);
}
```

Here's a dummy example:

```
Observable.Range(1, 3)
.MergeWithResultPropagation(item => new[]{
    Observable.Return(item * 2), 
    Observable.Return(item * 3)
}).Dump();
```

Is this an adequate way to solve the problem? Did I miss an extension method that does this?

Comment: Is `IObservable` your own interface because the [original one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd990377(v=vs.110).aspx) does not support `IEnumerable` and thus does not have the `SelectMany` extension. If so, could you include its definition too?

Comment: Oh, I now notice the [tag:system.reactive] tag. I guess it belongs to this package.

Comment: @t3chb0t Yup, that's right :p

Comment: I wanted to try your code out so I installed the `System.Reactive` package from NuGet and added the `System.Reactive` namespace in LINQPad but it still does not recognize this interface as `IEnumerable`. Could you tell me what else I need to do?

Comment: @t3chb0t Did you include all dependecies, such as `system.reactive.core`, `system.reactive.infrastructure`, etc...?

Comment: I got it working now. Thx.

Comment: If you want to keep the first item in each set then the `Union` might not be the right extension for the job. Did you mean to use `Concat`? The `Union` does not make sense in this example because there will never be more then one same result. `Union` means `[ 1, 2 ].Union([2, 3]) = [1, 2, 3]` whereas the same with `Concat` would be `[1, 2, 2, 3]`

Comment: @t3chb0t Well Yes I could use `Concat` instead, but it won't matter on my scenario since I am using reference type types, without equals implementation. It's something you might include on your review if you make one though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Union vs Concat

As you addmited, there is no need to use the `Union` extension because no two items will ever have the same value. `Concat` would be more appropriate because it'll better show what is going on.

Difference between the two is that

```
[ 1, 2 ].Union([2, 3]) = [1, 2, 3]
```

whereas the same with `Concat` would be

```
[ 1, 2 ].Concat([2, 3]) = [1, 2, 2, 3]
```

because of the not clear intention I had a hard time understanding this short code. The descriptions says something else then the implementation.

---

## Zip

I don't know any extension that could do the same job but I think this one could be expressed cleaner by first producing the results and then *zipping* each result with the corresponding item that lead to this result using the `Zip` extension. I also think that it's nicer to use `Enumerable.Repeat` rather then  `new []{}`

```
return 
    src
        .Select(x => elems(x))
        .Zip(src, (results, x) => results.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(Observable.Return(x), 1)))
        .SelectMany(z => z)
        .SelectMany(x => x);
```

## Functional

To make it even cleaner I suggest encapsulating the `Concat` in its own method so the *final* extension could be:

```
public static IObservable<T> MergeWithResultPropagation3<T>(this IObservable<T> values, Func<T, IEnumerable<IObservable<T>>> factory)
{
    return
        values
            .Select(x => factory(x))
            .Zip(values, AppendValue())
            .SelectMany(z => z)
            .SelectMany(x => x);

    Func<IEnumerable<IObservable<T>>, T, IEnumerable<IObservable<T>>> AppendValue()
    {
        return (results, value) => results.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(Observable.Return(value), 1));
    }
}
```

---

## yield return

Alternatively to `new []{}` and `Concat` you could make the helper work with `yield return`

```
public static IObservable<T> MergeWithResultPropagation3<T>(this IObservable<T> values, Func<T, IEnumerable<IObservable<T>>> factory)
{
    return
        values
            .Select(x => factory(x))
            .Zip(values, (results, value) => AppendValue(results, value))
            .SelectMany(z => z)
            .SelectMany(x => x);

    IEnumerable<IObservable<T>> AppendValue(IEnumerable<IObservable<T>> results, T value)
    {
        foreach (var result in results) yield return result;
        yield return Observable.Return(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: I had a look at zip as well but for some reason I than discarded it. Good to see it in action again, I barely use it. Looks good except for that Enumerable repeat, I prefer to create an array instance :p